# Jolt transform specific key values to lower case

Tags: json, jolt

I need to do some JSON transformation using JOLT.
Documentation for this software is so poorly written and unstructured that I, software developer with 30+ years of experience cannot figure it out. If someone can help me, I will appreciate it greatly.
So my JSON contains several keys that ends in "DateRange". I.e.

```
{
 "client": {},
 "orderHistory": {
   ...
   "firstOrderDateRange" : "In 90 days",
   "lastOrderDateRange" : "IN 30 Days",
   ...
  }
}
```

I need to convert these values to lower case.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **toLower** function along with **modify** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*DateRange": "=toLower(@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The Demo on https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/
[image]